# Cool rush of air uphill

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english

Do you know the word to describe a cool rushing current of uphill air? I think it has something to do with the air coming from a cool place on a warm day.

Comment: Cool air rushes down, not up.

Comment: @RegDwigнt _cool_ air goes up when it meets _cooler_ air. :)

Comment: @Frank If it's in a rush it ain't cool. If it were cool, it would just chill.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for *[Updraft](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/updraft)*. This fits almost exactly what you're describing and can be used for both indoor and outdoor settings.

"Do you feel this updraft?"

"Yes. Let me close the window."

Note: Niall's answer gives the British-English form, *updraught*, which is likely a more correct word that you were after. It's worth mentioning that they both are identical in meaning.

Answer (score 2):

This can be called a **thermal**.

In the context in which you asked it's very similar to *updraught* but there are ways that the words could be used differently.

Regarding @RegDwight's comment, these are caused by a body of air becoming heated and rising; cooler air will be drawn into the vacuum created when this happens. If this occurs on a hill it can cause cool air to be drawn uphill.

The spelling *updraught* has been used here instead of *updraft* as the question has the British-English tag.

Answer (score 0):

The wikibooks *[High School Earth Science/Air Movement](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/High_School_Earth_Science/Air_Movement)* document, in its *[Mountain and Valley Breezes](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/High_School_Earth_Science/Air_Movement#Mountain_and_Valley_Breezes)* section, refers to cooling breezes that move uphill as *valley breezes*.  Also see wikipedia's *[Mountain breeze and valley breeze](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_breeze_and_valley_breeze)* article.  Note, in the *[Land and Sea Breezes](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/High_School_Earth_Science/Air_Movement#Land_and_Sea_Breezes)* section, similar cooling breezes moving onshore and uphill are called *sea breezes*.

Generally, a warm wind moving uphill is called *[anabatic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anabatic_wind)*, and a downhill wind, typically but not always warm, is *[katabatic wind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katabatic_wind)*.  (Typically, [adiabatic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic) warming occurs as a parcel of air descends and compresses, and adiabatic cooling as it ascends.)  Many of the 85 to 100 or so individually-named winds listed on wikipedia's *[Category:Winds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Winds)* and *[List of local winds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_local_winds)* pages (such as *[Chinook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinook_wind)*, *[Föhn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foehn_wind)*, *[Santa Ana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Ana_winds)*, and *[Zonda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zonda_wind)* winds) are katabatic and hot.  Some cool winds are the *[tramontane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tramontane)*, *[Cierzo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cierzo)*, *[mistral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mistral_%28wind%29)*, and *[Piteraq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piteraq)*.  *[Valley exit jets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valley_exit_jet)* typically are cool downhill winds.  *[Orographic lift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orographic_lifting)* refers to air cooling and drying as it is forced up a mountain slope. (Also see *Orographic Lifting and Rain Shadows* at [waterencyclopedia.com](http://www.waterencyclopedia.com/Ce-Cr/Climate-Moderator-Water-as-a.html) and *Some Basics of Mountain Flow* at [blogspot.com](http://lukemweather.blogspot.com/2011/03/some-basics-of-mountain-flow.html).)

Summary:  Relevant terms include *valley breeze, sea breeze,  anabatic,  valley exit jets,* and *orographic lift*.